# Query from Join 2 table subqueries without where or Query from joined table with where is fasster

Tags: sql, join

Assume I have 2 tables `A` (`ID, col1, col2`) and `B` (`ID, col1, col2`).

Is it better to write

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM A 
     WHERE col1 = 1) A 
JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM B 
     WHERE col2 = 2) B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

or rather:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE A.col1 = 1 
  AND B.col2 = 2
```

Comment: You should check the explain plan: the DBMS could for example optimize the query such that the first and the second are made (almost) the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's better to use joins.

Joining data with `WHERE` clause does NOT allow you to grab data like `LEFT|RIGHT JOIN` does. `WHERE` clause allows you to grab data in the way in which `INNER JOIN` does.

For further details, please see: [Visual representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)